# How can I modify verbiage for the Telerik blazor scheduler?

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik, telerik-blazor

Is there a way to modify the verbiage for the "all day" field?

[image]

Comment: "all day" doesn't appear to be the default in the scheduler component, so how are you enabling it?  Is it possible your code is adding this? (I'm surprised that the A in All isn't capitalised, which makes me suspect it's not part of the control)

Comment: @Neil I believe it is "all day" by default.

Comment: @Neil - the "all day" is their default message and like you I am surprise the A is not capitalized as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it through the Localization system that allows you to modify most of the keywords in the components.

In the file TelerikMessages.resx, the name of your field is Scheduler_AllDay.

[Doc](https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/globalization/localization)